# How to replace part of a Timestamp using .where()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, series

I have a dataframe that contains a few timestamps. I am trying to find certain timestamps that don't meet a condition and compute their new timestamp value based on pieces from both another timestamp and the current timestamp being tested.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [pd.Timestamp(2021, 1, 1, 12), pd.Timestamp(2021, 1, 2, 
                                 12), pd.Timestamp(2021, 1, 3, 12)], 
                        'col2': [pd.Timestamp(2021, 1, 4, 12), pd.Timestamp(2021, 1, 5, 
                                12), pd.Timestamp(2021, 1, 6, 12)]})
print(df)
#                 col1                col2
# 0 2021-01-01 12:00:00 2021-01-04 12:00:00
# 1 2021-01-02 12:00:00 2021-01-05 12:00:00
# 2 2021-01-03 12:00:00 2021-01-06 12:00:00
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
testDate = pd.Timestamp(2021, 1, 2, 16)
df['newCol'] = df['col1'].where(df['col1'].dt.date <= testDate.date(), pd.Timestamp(year=testDate.year, month=testDate.month, day=testDate.day, hour=df['col1'].dt.hour))
```

I get an error though about ambiguity:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

If I remove the last bit `hour=df['col1'].dt.hour`, the code will run, so I know it has to do with that, but I don't understand why it's complaining about truthiness since that little piece of the code isn't testing any conditions, it's just assigning. I thought it was because I'm trying to compute the new value using the values that are being iterated over, but if I try this process using integers instead of timestamps, it runs just fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': [4,5,6]})
print(df)
#   col1  col2
# 0     1     4
# 1     2     5
# 2     3     6

testInt = 2
df['newCol'] = df['col1'].where(df['col1'] < testInt, df['col1'] + 2)
print(df)
#   col1  col2  newCol
# 0     1     4       1
# 1     2     5       4
# 2     3     6       5
```

What is the proper way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the target series first:

```
target = (pd.Series(testDate.normalize(), index=df.index)
            + (df['col1'] - df['col1'].dt.normalize()))

df['newCol'] = df['col1'].where(df['col1'] <= testDate, target)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                 col1                col2              newCol
0 2021-01-01 12:00:00 2021-01-04 12:00:00 2021-01-01 12:00:00
1 2021-01-02 12:00:00 2021-01-05 12:00:00 2021-01-02 12:00:00
2 2021-01-03 12:00:00 2021-01-06 12:00:00 2021-01-02 12:00:00

>>> target
0   2021-01-02 12:00:00
1   2021-01-02 12:00:00
2   2021-01-02 12:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

> If I remove the last bit hour=df['col1'].dt.hour, the code will run, so I know it has to do with that, but I don't understand why it's complaining about truthiness since that little piece of the code isn't testing any conditions

The problem is not the condition. `pd.Timestamp` take some parameters (year, month, day, ...). Each of these parameters takes a scalar value not a vector (`df['col1'].dt.hour`). That's why the function raises a `ValueError` exception.